# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'

Tags: c++-cli

I made a wrapper for a C++ dll in C++/CLI to be used with a c++ program.  When I call a function that has a declaration of a class from that wrapper, I get this error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in EMWCADLink.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Nom, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7210645d4d5e3a39' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I added this wrapper dll in the "Add reference..." , can anyone help me plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dll you are wrapping must be in the directory of your executable or on the path.  The most likely case is that when the run time attempts to load your wrapper the wrapper looks for the c++ dll and fails.

Comment: the prb that i can use the dll in such places

Comment: What? I didn't understand you comment.